# Google Chrome Native and Sandbox Disk Security

Tags: security, google-chrome, native, sandbox, google-nativeclient

How secure is the Google Native Sandbox Disk?

If a sandbox application using google native APIs was to place a highly secure file in the Chrome Sandbox Disk, is it possible for an program outside of Chrome or another Chrome Native client to get access to such data?

One would hope that the Sandbox is completely hidden / encrypted from other sandboxed apps and external apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programs outside of Chrome (running under the same user as Chrome or as root/administrator) can access any data saved in the HTML5 filesystem by NaCl or javascript. NaCl applications and javascript from a different domain can't access them.

Answer (score 1):

From here:
https://developers.google.com/native-client/faq

It sounds like you should use native client in order to "...Handling browser-side encryption and decryption for an enterprise application."
So I guess you can have a powerful encryption for your data by using NaCL and making sure you use a good encryption lib.